# RDS RemoteApps won't run from correct server

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have a Windows 2012 R2 RDS Farm with a Gateway and Web Access installed on the same server.  I have ports 80, 443, and 3389 forwarded so external users can get to this server.  We can sign in and see the list of RemoteApps, but when I run one I can see that the server is running them and not sending the requests to the broker(s) like it should.  (I then expect the brokers to send the request to one of the hour RDS hosts I have set up.)

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I need to look at?  I found some GP entries that should force the server to send the requests to the brokers, but for some reason they're all wanting to run on the RDS Gatewy (which is absolutely NOT set up as an RDS Host).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I am required to have the broker role installed on my gateway.